# Is it bad practice to use informal arguments when evaluating limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, soft-question

I often see slightly informal ways of evaluating limits. For example:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\frac{x}{e^x}}{3+\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1+0+0}{3+0} =\frac{1}{3}$$

I think this is not a proof, rather a bit of an sketchy argument.

Is it bad practice to evaluate limits like this? Or is it okay?

Comment: In this case you're applying known theorems

Comment: An intermediate step would be to put $lim$ in front of each term in the num and denom. How formal does it have to be? I don't think it is a bad practice since all limits of individual terms exist, which is of course a necessary condition, but I am sure you already knew that :) Want to have a proof, perhaps then epsilon delta?

Comment: I'd say this depends on the audience. If you are going to start the first lesson of an undergraduate course like that, then yes, it would be bad practise. If you, on the other hand, would start to give detailed explanations on why this particular example is evaluated like this in a mathematical paper in some distinguished math journal, that would be bad practise, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you just explain the properties used to calculate this limit: arithmetic laws, etc.